# Testing by component name using React testing library

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test if the correct prop is being passed to a component. In enzyme its easily done by:

```
const control = enzyme.mount(<Test />);
expect(control.find(<CompToTest />).props().MyProp).toEqual(expectedProp);
```

How can I achieve the same result using react-testing-library? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can't access props with `react-testing-library`, that's by design.

Instead, you need to test that what your component renders is correct.

If you think about it, it makes sense because ultimately you don't care about what props get passed, but you want to test that what gets rendered is correct.

Comment: So you're saying I'll have to test `<CompToTest />` is being rendered with the right data? If so, I really cant because its a third party library. `<Test />` is my wrapper around it.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What is this 3rd party component doing? Usually, I would suggest to mock it and avoid testing it

Comment: `<CompToTest />` receives a `untreatedColumnDef` prop and `<Test />` takes in a `columnDef`. Before passing in the data to `columnDef` I need to change `untreatedColumnDef` data and make it ready to be consumed by `<Test />`. I want to test that the data is being processed correctly before being passed through to `<Test />`.

Comment: But is `Test` a component you created only for testing purposes?

Comment: in any case, <Compotest > doesw not really exist in rendered final html, it exist ony it's content, so...